# Overiding a automated jQuery tab control with JavaScript forward/back arrows?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There are similar questions on this topic, but not the same. I have a scrolling jQuery feature that uses tabs to select and is automated. I can not alter this layout easily because it is dynamic and based on how many items are in selected array are passed in PHP. The mark-up code looks like this... (see PHP at end)

```
<div id="tabs" class="clients" style="display:none;">
 <a class="" href="#">1</a>
 <a class="" href="#">2</a>
 <a class="" href="#">3</a>
 <a class="" href="#">4</a>
 <a class="activeSlide" href="#">5</a>
</div>
```

As it scrolls through or tab is selected, it becomes the activeSlide class. I plan to on some clients use a display:none (in CSS) to hide the tabs and would like to include this arrow layout for my forward/back with some type of JavaScript tied in...

```
<div id="slider-controls">
  <a href="#" id="prev"><img src="_img/_sliders/prev.gif" width="41" height="17" /></a>      <span><img src="_img/blank.gif" width="1" height="1" /></span>
  <a href="#" id="next"><img src="_img/_sliders/next.gif" width="41" height="17" /></a>
</div>
```

Any insight on an easier fix using existing jQuery, what I should be looking for and if it is possible to simply add JavaScript to over-ride the existing code with new forward/back tabs.

Now here is my PHP with code at this point to see where this is all coming from, you can see I have a pause button as well (not as important) and a client case study that is not in all items, so an if/else. More important than just making it work, I want to learn a better way of figuring this out and how it works for those that have a little more time.

```
<?php if ($num_projs > 0){ ?>
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="photos">
                <!-- dump all photos here, then manipulate them via tabs with jQuery -->
                <?php 
                foreach($projects as $project){
                    if($project['project_media_use'] == 'video' and $project['project_video'] != ''){
                ?>
                <div id="<?php print stripslashes($project['project_name']);?>" title="<?php print stripslashes($project['project_desc']);?>" class="video"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php print $project['project_video'];?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="606" height="348" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <div id="<?php print stripslashes($project['project_name']);?>" title="<?php print stripslashes($project['project_desc']);?>" style="background-image: url('_img/_cms_uploads/_projects/<?php print $project['project_image'];?>')"></div>
                <?php } } ?>

            </div>
            <div id="slider-bottom"> <!-- added display:none; to hide tabs - Shane -->
                <div style="display:none;" id="tabs" class="clients"></div> <!-- tabs are created automatically based on number of divs within "photos" div -->
                <?php if($clientCaseStudy != ''){?>
                    <div id="links">
                <!-- shane -->
                    <a><img src="_img/_sliders/pause.gif" id="pause" width="20" height="17"/></a><span><img src="_img/blank.gif" width="1" height="1" /></span>
                    <a id="prev"><img src="_img/_sliders/prev.gif" width="41" height="17" /></a><span><img src="_img/blank.gif" width="1" height="1" /></span><a id="next"><img src="_img/_sliders/next.gif" width="41" height="17" /></a><br />
                        <a style="text-align: left;" href="/<?php print $clientCaseStudy + " ";?>" rel="casestudy">CASE STUDY &gt;</a> <div style="clear:left"></div>
                 <!-- shane -->

                </div><?php } else{?>
                    <div id="links"><a><img src="_img/_sliders/pause.gif" id="pause" width="20" height="17"/></a><span><img src="_img/blank.gif" width="1" height="1" /></span>
                    <a id="prev"><img src="_img/_sliders/prev.gif" width="41" height="17" /></a><span><img src="_img/blank.gif" width="1" height="1" /></span><a id="next"><img src="_img/_sliders/next.gif" width="41" height="17" /></a>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

The site is using a Twitter Bootstrap if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out and thought I would share in case others run into the same. It involved manipulating a JavaScript file, adding the last two lines of code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#photos').cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'slow', 
    timeout: 9000, 
    pager:  '#tabs',
    before:  onBefore, 
    after:   onAfter,
    next:   '#next', //added shane
    prev:   '#prev'  //added shane
});
```

then adding something of this nature to the other file...

```
<div class="nav">
                <a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
                <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
            </div>
```

...giving me the ability to navigate or use tabs. 
This website http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html was very helpful in figuring all of this out and looks to be apart of the jQuery Cycle Plugin.